# Typescript: Is there any way to use inline require but still get type checking?

Tags: typescript, require, migrate

I am migrating a legacy code to typescript, and some of the files use inline requires for **performance boost** (lazy loading):

```js
//DataClass.js

const Data = {
  get Phones() {
    return require('./phones.ts').default;
  },
  get Users() {
    return require('./users.ts').default;
  },
```

before converting the file to `ts`, the intelisense worked completely fine, and gave me autocomplete for all the props of phone and users (both of them are ts files). but after changing the file extention to `ts`, the require statements return `any` and I am losing the types.

I can't convert the code to `await import`, because it means changing all the legacy codebase (for supporting async). 
I don't mind keeping this module as a `.js` file, but then I am losing the types on every `.ts` file that imports the data from this file, so even though phones are strongly typed, I can get the benefit of it.

Is there any way to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not a solution but a workaround (I am the OP), I decided to keep the file with its `js` extention, and create a separate `ts` file with the same name, for getting the types. 
When there are two files with the same name, the bundler prefers the `js` one, so the content of the `js` file with the inline require will be used, but typescript compiler prefer the `ts` file so I get all the type checks while developing, and when running `tsc`, typscript will generate the correct declarations for the file.

```js
//DataClass.js (real file, will be included in the real bundle)

export const Data = {
  get Phones() {
    return require('./phones.ts').default;
  },
  get Users() {
    return require('./users.ts').default;
  }
}
```

```js
//DataClass.ts (fake file, will help typescript compiler to generate declaration file for the index)

import phones from './phones.ts';
import users from './users.ts'

export const Data = {phones, users};
```

This is definitely not a solution, just a nasty workaround. But sadly this is the only solution I got till now. If anybody knows of a better solution, please post it here.